# Расположить нижние блоки под верхними

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Здравствуйте, есть проблема, есть сайт в длину нужно блоков 5 расположить, но блоки будут разной высоты (в блоках будут картинки), как расположить нижние блоки под верхними? 
Вот примерно как нужно:

[image]

Comment: я бы посмотрел как сделано в исходнике примера

Comment: полностью поддерживаю. автор, ты смотрел через инспектор кода этот сайт, что на картинке?

Comment: `расположить нижние блоки под верхними` они и так уже там.

Comment: @Gerome, это пример как нужно сдлеать

Comment: @mountpoint, http://demo.designwall.com/wallpress/ вот там это шаблон, там не понятно там каждому элементу top left right высчитывают и прописывают в style, посмотрите может вы что поймёте буду очень благодарен

Comment: @АЛСУ, тут 4 блока в примере...

Comment: @Gerome http://demo.designwall.com/wallpress/  вот пример

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/6wHdQ/

```css
.vline {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.vline img {
  margin: 0px;
  display: block;
  margin: 5px 0px 0px 0px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.vline div {
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 14px;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 1px #000;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 1190px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="vline">
    <div>Вот все думают, что женщины придумали феминизм, чтоб сесть на шею мужикам.
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/190/200/sports/1/" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div>Вот все думают, что женщины придумали феминизм, чтоб сесть на шею мужикам.
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/190/300/sports/2/" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div>Вот все думают, что женщины придумали феминизм, чтоб сесть на шею мужикам.
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/190/100/sports/3/" alt="" />
    </div>
  </div>



  <div class="vline">
    <div>Вот все думают, что женщины придумали феминизм, чтоб сесть на шею мужикам.
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/190/100/sports/3/" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div>Вот все думают, что женщины придумали феминизм, чтоб сесть на шею мужикам.
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/190/200/sports/1/" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div>Вот все думают, что женщины придумали феминизм, чтоб сесть на шею мужикам.
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/190/300/sports/2/" alt="" />
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="vline">
    <div>Вот все думают, что женщины придумали феминизм, чтоб сесть на шею мужикам.
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/190/300/sports/2/" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div>Вот все думают, что женщины придумали феминизм, чтоб сесть на шею мужикам.
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/190/100/sports/3/" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div>Вот все думают, что женщины придумали феминизм, чтоб сесть на шею мужикам.
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/190/200/sports/1/" alt="" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="vline">
    <div>Вот все думают, что женщины придумали феминизм, чтоб сесть на шею мужикам.
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/190/200/sports/1/" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div>Вот все думают, что женщины придумали феминизм, чтоб сесть на шею мужикам.
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/190/300/sports/2/" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div>Вот все думают, что женщины придумали феминизм, чтоб сесть на шею мужикам.
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/190/100/sports/3/" alt="" />
    </div>
  </div>



  <div class="vline">
    <div>Вот все думают, что женщины придумали феминизм, чтоб сесть на шею мужикам.
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/190/100/sports/3/" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div>Вот все думают, что женщины придумали феминизм, чтоб сесть на шею мужикам.
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/190/200/sports/1/" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div>Вот все думают, что женщины придумали феминизм, чтоб сесть на шею мужикам.
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/190/300/sports/2/" alt="" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Вообще там используется библиотека [masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/)

Comment: Gerome, как его использовать? читал, ничего не выходит

Comment: так надо не только читать, а еще и пробовать.

Answer (score -1):

Юзайте inline-block . В отличии от float, inline-block позволяет позиционировать блоки как показано в примере.

Comment: @Archiolidius такого не получится, если юзать только inline-block